# JHipster OAuth2 server - login page for /oauth/authorize

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, jhipster

**tl;dr;**

I want to make custom working login page when user is redirected to /oauth/authorize, in [jhipster template app](https://jhipster.github.io/) I manage to display my login page but it is just redirecting to itself no matter what credentials are used or if I remove

```
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
```

from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter page works fine but /oauth/token returns:

```
error: "unauthorized"
error_description: "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
```

**Long description:**
I'm using jhipster template app for resource server with some small admin front end. Except of this I want other client apps to be able to use my resource server, but user login should stay on my app.
Example Journey:

1. Client app is redirecting user to my app:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/authorize?
      response_type=code&client_id=kbExplorer&redirect_uri=http://localhost
   ```
2. Login page is served for a user
3. User choose scopes he wants to give
4. Server is redirecting to `redirect_uri` with authorization code
5. App uses code to get refresh token

   ```
   127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token?grand_type=authorization_code&code={code}
   ```

This is typical journey.

Problem starts when I want to change basic http login window, to my own login page.

First thing I've done was changing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/api/register")
            .antMatchers("/api/activate")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init")
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish")
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .antMatchers("/console/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //.httpBasic().realmName("LES")
                //.and()

                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/logput").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

Thanks to that I'm getting custom login page served from mvc controller:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

But there is a problem right now, when I go to `/oauth/authorize` login page is served and it is ok, except of whatever you will put there it will always redirect you back to this login page.

I've noticed that if I only remove:

```
@Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    //.httpBasic().realmName("LES")
                    //.and()

                    // This is the line I'm removing:
                    //.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")

                    //.and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/logput").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
        }
```

Whole login works fine. But now admin app stops (this is pure jhipster angularjs template). Just opening this app produces an error:

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
exception: "java.lang.IllegalStateException"
message: "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: User not found!"
path: "/api/account"
status: 500
timestamp: "2016-01-22T11:33:08.286+0000"
```

Attempt to log in by default grand_type=password produce:

```
error: "unauthorized"
error_description: "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
```

This is my `OAuth2ServerConfiguration` (Basically its pure jhipser template):

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Inject
        private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")) // csfr (my own change)
                    .disable()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/dump/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/shutdown/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/beans/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/configprops/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/env/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/liquibase/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        Environment env;

        @Inject
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Inject
        private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Inject
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {

            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            if(env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
                clients.jdbc(dataSource);
            }else{
                clients
                        .jdbc(dataSource)
                        .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getClientid())
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
                        .secret(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getSecret())
                        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getTokenValidityInSeconds())
                        .and()
                        .withClient("kbExplorer")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
                        .secret("kbExplorerAppSecret")
                        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5)
                        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question is:

How to make login page works, without breaking api in same time?

Answer (score 1):

I had wrong matchers, login page was not working in my first option because I had no matcher for `"/login"` in `configure` method.
`SecurityConfiguration` class should be like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize","/login", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```